# how to return a 400 errro_message in pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

I want to return the format:

`res['result'] == False` and `res['error_message'] == 'Unknown User'`

How to do it in `views.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to return a JSON response? In that case set your renderer as `json` and return a dict containing the values you want.

```
def myview(request):
    return {'result': False, 'error_message': 'Unknown User'}

config.add_view(myview, renderer='json')
```

Obviously you'll need to add other stuff for your specific view/route combination, but this is all covered in the Pyramid documentation